# Symfony 2 + Doctrine, joining multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities: Products, ProductFeatures (like Color, Size, etc) and ProductFeaturesVarient(like red,orange,green,yellow,32,34,36, etc).

Product can have features like color, size etc. Each feature can have variants. Like Polo T-shirt with Red, Orange Color and 32, 34 Size.

I want to relate those 3 entities by join table. I know I have to create an entity something like ProductFeatureVariant but I don't know how I define relationship.

So, 4th entity ProductFeatureVariant  with fields: product_id, feature_id and feature_variant_id.

Can anyone help me to define this?

Comment: You normally wouldn't need to create the join tables yourself. Use relations (product to feature, feature to color, feature to size, etc)

Comment: Seems like my table names are confusing. Here is the basic structure I am expecting

**Product**: id, Name
**Features**: id, Feature_title
**FeatureVariant**: id, feature_id, variant_title

Final combined table should look like:
**ProductFeatureVariant**: product_id, feature_id and variant_id

Answer (score 3):

You will just need 3 One-To-Many relations, which can be bidirectional.

```
/** @Entity */
class Product
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(length=140) */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductFeature", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $features;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->features = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class ProductFeature
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(length=140) */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductFeatureVariant", mappedBy="productFeature")
     */
    private $variants;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variants = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class ProductFeatureVariant
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(length=140) */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductFeature", inversedBy="variants")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $productFeature;
}
```

Using the query builder you could make simple joins.

```
//select products with a certain color
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('p')
    ->from('Product', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.features', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('f.variants', 'v')
    ->where('v.name = :color')
    ->setParameter('color', $color);
```

Answer (score 0):

As ProductFeaturesVariant already linked to the ProductFeatures I would avoid the references to the ProductFeatures table so it would be just a ManyToMany relation between the Product and ProductFeaturesVariant table. If you ever reassign a ProductFeaturesVariant to other Feature your triple-link table will became inconsistent.